# How can I use a contribution page to allow user to make payment against an existing pending contribution record?

Tags: civicontribute, invoice

Here's my use case:

Users make a document submission via a separate third party system. The document is manually assessed and if suitable, is accepted. The user then needs to make a payment, but they need an invoice in order to do that.

I'd like them to use CiviCRM to make the payment online. In order to send an invoice from Civi I need to have a contribution record already in place, so if I create this record and give it a pending status, how can the user's subsequent payment be logged against this record, rather than a new record being created when they submit the contribution page?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me more like a pledge use case. That is not something I have much experience with, but I'd think you could enter a pledge for them and when they make the contribution, it would be used against the pledge.

If you don't otherwise use pledges, you could even rename it invoices.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this process you need to write an Extension - this will be an bit of work

One way to do this - any contribution created against the user can be viewed in user dashboard - http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/user?reset=1

you can add a new button to user dashboard and On submit the button/link which will redirect you to the payment screen based on you payment processor setup. Then you can collect the amount and complete the transaction